# "Could not find function object.size" when using lm.mids and pool on mice output

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to run a regression with and without `mice::pool` on some imputed data:

```r
# without pooling
model_1 <-lm.mids(out ~ x + y, data = data)
summary(model_1)

# with pooling:
model_1_fit <- with(data = data, exp = lm(out ~ x + y))
model_1_pooled <- summary(pool(model_1_fit, data = data))
```

Whether I do one or the other I get the following error message:

> Error in object.size(obj) : could not find function "object.size"

I understand this is a function in the utils packages, which is loaded, and it seems to work fine when I use it on a single object:

```r
object.size(data)
143392 bytes
```

I searched for this error on Google and find nothing helpful.
Any idea of what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when i had unloaded the utils package,loaded it back and then restarted the R and it worked fine.